# Adding values to an array works in script but not in function

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am trying to create an array in php to send to a function that I can use to receive user information.

The issue I am having is that the array is "duplicating" its values. This is a very basic issue I am having but I can't seem to get over this.

This is how I am doing it :

```
$info = array('intActive', 'intUserRole');
```

from doing this when I var_dump in the function I get this :

```
public function employee_info($where, $info) {// Used through out to get info on employees from Assessor table
//        var_dump($info);
```

> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "intAssessorID" } array(1) { [0]=>
>   string(13) "intAssessorID" } // This should not be duplicated

However, what confuses me when I do a var_dump of $info directly underneath $info  I get what I need :

```
 $info = array('intActive', 'intUserRole');   
        var_dump($info);
```

> array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "intActive" [1]=> string(11) "intUserRole"
>   }

Edit 1 :

```
 $info = array('intActive', 'intUserRole');   
        var_dump($info);     
        $emp_info = $this -> m_global -> employee_info($where, $info);
```

Edit 2 :

My entire script :

```
class MY_Userarea extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $login = $this -> session -> userdata('logged_in');
        $id = $this -> session -> userdata('userID');
        $where[":id"] = $id; // This works fine
        $info = array('intActive', 'intUserRole'); // This works until it gets sent to a function called employee_info   
        var_dump($info);     
        $emp_info = $this -> m_global -> employee_info($where, $info);

        if (($login !== TRUE) || ($emp_info["intActive"] !== 1) || ($emp_info["intUserRole"] === 0)) { // If no role, not activated , or not logged in then deny access
            $denyaccess = TRUE;
            $this -> m_global -> access_denied($denyaccess);
        }
    }
```

My employee_info script :

```
public function employee_info($where, $info) {// Used through out to get info on employees from Assessor table
    var_dump($info);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tableAssessor WHERE 1 ";
// Check for my where keys that I manually place.
        if (array_key_exists(":active", $where)) {
            $sql .= " AND intActive = :active ";
        }

        if (array_key_exists(":role", $where)) {
            $sql .= " AND intUserRole = :role ";
        }

        if (array_key_exists(":id", $where)) {
            $sql .= " AND intAssessorID = :id ";
        }

        if (array_key_exists(":email", $where)) {
            $sql .= " AND txtEmail = :email ";
        }

        $employee_info = $this -> db -> conn_id -> prepare($sql);
        $employee_info -> execute($where);

        if ($employee_info) {
            if ($employee_info -> rowCount() > 0) {
                foreach ($employee_info -> fetchall() as $row) {
                    foreach ($info as $in) { // for each of the elements in the $info array use that to grab the row needed. (this works with a variable perfectly, but I want to expand it so I can retrieve more information with one function call rather then multiple calls.
                        $information[$in] = $row[$in];
                    }
                }
                return $information;
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show us what happens between `$info = array(...)` and calling the `employee_info(...)` function?

Comment: updated the original post

Comment: Hmm... is `intAssessorID` an element of `$where` or `$info`?

Comment: It is a element of $info. Where just holds the user id like so :  $where[":id"] = $id;

Comment: Updated the original post w/ comments

Comment: a few days late but are you still looking for the solution to this? as what gets displayed is not a multidimensional array, its just the array but twice, so it looks like you're just 'echoing' it out twice. sure enough you have var_dump($info); in  both your extension and in your employee function - anyway, hope you've fixed it by now

Answer (score 0):

First problem (your output is happening twice) is because you are calling `var_dump` twice, once in your `__construct` and once in your function. `__construct` is called before any other function within your class, so it won't be necessary to call `var_dump` again in `employee_info`.

If you take the call our of `employee_info` is your result what you are after?